# response.content.readasstringasync() to object

Tags: c#, response, dotnet-httpclient, httpresponsemessage

My problem is that I cannot extract an object sent by an API, despite I have the schema of the object either in the API or in the client. My code:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        
        
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44237/");
        client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;

       
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Front/Subm?IdSubmission=1xxx").Result;

        try
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                
                
                string Result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                Submission sub = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Submission>(Result);

                return View(sub);
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

structure received in result is

[image]

Comment: First of all its an `async` method so use await instead of `.Result`.
`HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Front/Subm?IdSubmission=1xxx");`

Second, check if the string you get is the correct object

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the instance `JavaScriptSerializer` which is created in your code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Submission sub = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Submission>(Result);
```

Try to modify your code like this:

```
string Result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Submission sub = jsonSerializer.DeserializeObject(Result);
```