# Multipart/fom-data request

Tags: c#, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

I need to create multipart/form-data request to captcha recognition API.
On API description page I found Request template:

```
<form method="post" action="https://captchasiteapi.com/in.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="post">
Your key:
<input type="text" name="key" value="YOUR_APIKEY">
Captcha file:
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload and get ID">
/<form>
```

I wrote this method based on HttpClient:

```
private async Task<string> UploadRequestAsync(string url, string filePath, string profileApiKey)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    formData.Add(new StringContent("post"), "hidden", "method");
    formData.Add(new StringContent(profileApiKey), "key");
    formData.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", fileName);
    formData.Add(new StringContent("Upload and get ID"), "submit");
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, formData);
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode){
        return null;
    }
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

But really don't sure how to create `<input type="hidden" name="method" value="post">` line. How can I create 3 values in form?
The result of API is string like "OK|CaptchaValue", So `Task<string>` should be ok.

Comment: SO, what have you tied and where have you failed?

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: I've got error response from API so i think i did something wrong. By the way, how can i output my request as a string to console? Just to be sure that my created request structure and given template are the same.

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: also, take a look here for your answer on getting the value returned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011610/response-content-readasstringasync-to-object